# Como retornar o resultado de um select com prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysql

Gente, não estou conseguindo retornar o resultado de uma busca com prepared statement.

Eis o código:

```
public function search($obj) {
        $connection = new Connection();
        $this->db = $connection->conectar();

        /* String SQL de buscar todos os registros */
        $stringSQL = "SELECT * FROM fornecedor WHERE cnpj = :cnpj";

        $statement = $this->db->prepare($stringSQL);

        /* parâmetros do prepared statement */
        $statement->bindparam(":cnpj", $obj->getCnpj());

        /* executa a query */
        $statement->execute();

        $result = $statement->get_result();

        unset($this->db);
        return $result;
    }
```

Estou com o seguinte erro:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::get_result() in C:\xampp\htdocs\inove\gentelella-master\production\Classes\Persistencia\FornecedorCrud.php on line 123

Alguma ajuda?

Obrigado

Comment: Está misturando PDO com uma função MySQLi...

Comment: @Inkeliz obrigado. É verdade.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public function search($obj) {
    $connection = new Connection();
    $this->db = $connection->conectar();

    /* String SQL de buscar todos os registros */
    $stringSQL = "SELECT * FROM fornecedor WHERE cnpj = :cnpj";

    $statement = $this->db->prepare($stringSQL);

    /* parâmetros do prepared statement */
    $statement->bindparam(":cnpj", $obj->getCnpj());

    /* executa a query */
    $statement->execute();

    /* retorna o resultado */
    $statement->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $statement;
}
```

$stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // Esta linha retorna todos os resultados encontrados no execute().. caso queira retornar um único resultado utilize $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); Não testei mais acredito estar funcionando.. Boa sorte!

Comment: Obrigado.
A única alteração que tive que fazer no seu código obter o resultado esperado foi:
$statement = $statement->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

Caso eu imprimisse apenas $statement, obteria PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT * FROM fornecedor WHERE cnpj = :cnpj ).

De qualquer forma, funcionou. Obrigado

Comment: Eu que agradeço.. que bom que consegui te ajudar!